# lead returns from clients using power bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to check the distribution of the returned leads (leads replaced by the company) by return reason and CID (campaign ID) using power BI. How should the dashboard look like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW46T.png)?

Power BI dashboard details in the indicators

Comment: A unique list and index() with match() ?